# Making a content generator Apache module that only works for text/html requests

Tags: http, module, content-type, apache

The title of this question may be a bit misleading. I couldn't quite think of anything better.

Here is my problem. I am developing an Apache module that needs to manipulate a bit of content in the requested HTML document (this document can be a file on the disk or may be dynamically generated by CGI or PHP) and so I am using libxml2 with it.

I developed something working, but the problem is that when the browser requests for a page, let's say

http://localhost/a.html

the module does it's job. But if that page has references to a javascript file, a.js, or a stylesheet file, a.css, they are not getting served.

The reason as I perceived by examining the logs is that, as the browser sends requests for a javascript file let's say

> [http://localhost/a.js]     //putting [] because of limit of 1 url per post.

Apache again runs my module, the module uses a HTML parser, so when the content is not HTML, it gives error and exits, the request is abandoned.

How can I make my module to work only for text/html requests ?

Comment: Hi! Sorry to bother you so many years later, but do you have an example of code for this module? I’m looking around and considering making a module that postparses html output like what you describe - after other modules and PHP - but can’t find much.

Comment: This code is too old for me to remember anything about it, but here it is: https://github.com/abhinav-upadhyay/mod_hoverin

Note that, it simply inserts a header in the body of the response (as far as I recall). I did not end up using libxml for parsing html. I hope you may be able to use this as inspiration. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that’s very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to make your module to decline the request. But if you don't figure how to do it you can just configure it in httpd.conf

```
AddHandler my-handler .html
```

Comment: yes that's how I am doing it currently. What other extensions should I put in the directive to make my module more fail-proof. some of the other popular extension I know are .shtml, .php,etc.